# how to make fputs function prompt wrong input and ask user to input again...program stopping instead of request for new input

Tags: c, function, if-statement, stderr, fputs

i'm doing calculation for result. user will input 3 type of result that is pass, fail & invalid. I need to have 1 more checking that is when user input result other than integer value it will be count as wrong input. By using fputs function, how can i ask user to input integer data only ? instead of stopping, program will ask user to input again until user input the correct data.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int test_result;
    int pass;
    int fail;
    int invalid;

    for (int trainee_total; trainee_total < 6; trainee_total++) {
        printf("Enter Result (Pass=1 Fail=2) :");

        if (scanf("%d", &test_result) != 1) {
            fputs("Wrong input\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }

        if (test_result == 1) {
            pass = pass + 1;
        } else if (test_result == 2) {
            fail = fail + 1;
        } else {
            invalid = invalid + 1;
        }
    }

    printf("The number of participants that passed is :  %d\n", pass);
    printf("The number of participants that failed is :  %d\n", fail);
    printf("Invalid input is :  %d\n", invalid);
}
```

Comment: Use a loop and loop around instead of breaking?

Comment: Please note that if `scanf` fails, it might leave the invalid input in the buffer. So if you use a loop with `scanf` then it will be infinite as you just attempt to parse the same invalid input over and over again. Instead use `fgets` to read a full line into a string, and then use e.g. `sscanf` to parse the string.

Comment: Can i use fgets inside  fputs function?

Comment: Cadefr6554, What do you expect with input like `"123abc\n"`?

Comment: What is the initial values of `pass`, `fail` and `invalid`? Hint: They are *not* zero.

Comment: Same with `trainee_total`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Read an int from the user
//   prompt       Prompte message to display to the user
//   errortext    Text to display upon wrong input
//
int GetIntFromUser(const char *prompt, const char *errortext)
{
  int value;
  while (1) {
    fputs(prompt, stdout);

    // Read the input
    if (scanf("%d", &value) != 1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", errortext);
      
      // Clear the input buffer
      int c;
      while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    }
    else {
      break; // Exit the loop if input is valid
    }
  }

  return value;
}


int main(void) {
  int pass = 0;   // initialize to 0 (mandatory)
  int fail = 0;   // initialize to 0 (mandatory)
  int invalid = 0;  // initialize to 0 (mandatory)

  for (int trainee_total = 0; trainee_total < 20; trainee_total++) {
  //                       ^
  //                        initialize to 0, (mandatory)

    // declare test_result here (better style)
    int test_result = GetIntFromUser("Enter Result (Pass=1 Fail=2) :", "Wrong input");

    if (test_result == 1) {
      pass = pass + 1;
    }
    else if (test_result == 2) {
      fail = fail + 1;
    }
    else {
      invalid = invalid + 1;
    }
  }

  printf("The number of participants that passed is :  %d\n", pass);
  printf("The number of participants that failed is :  %d\n", fail);
  printf("Invalid input is :  %d\n", invalid);
}
```

- The `GetIntFromUser` function is inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78025554/898348).
- The explanations are in the comments. The comments with `(mandatory)` are needed so the program is correct, The comments with `(better style)` just show that it is a better style.
- There is maybe still room for improvement for the `GetIntFromUser` function. If e.g. `11 22 33` is entered the program output looks kind of strange.

Comment: `GetIntFromUser()` --> infinite loop on end-of-file.

Comment: @Cadefr6554 please look at this [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78025554/898348) for correct handling of the EOF condition.

Answer (score 1):

To better detect and handle errors, I think it's more useful to use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read the input, and [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to parse the input.

The thing about `strtol` is that it can detect not only invalid input, but also input that begins with digits and followed by non-digits (like for example `"123abc"`).

Another important thing is that you should really put the input handling in its own function. That means you can use it again from multiple places without having to copy-paste code (which makes it so much harder for maintenance).

Another nice thing with a function is that it's easy to return not only the value that was read and parsed, but also a status saying if the input was valid or not.

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

// "Flush" the input buffer, i.e. read everything until either
// end-of-line (the newline) or end-of-file
// Can be used for any input stream
// Returns true if flushed to the end-of-line
// Returns false if flushed to the end-of-file
bool flush_input(FILE *stream)
{
    int c;

    // Read characters until newline or end of file
    while ((c = fgetc(stream)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        // Empty
    }

    // Returns true if newline, false otherwise
    return c == '\n';
}

// Read an int value from a stream
// This function is line-based, it assumes that the integer is alone on the line
// Pass a pointer to the variable you want to read into using the pointer-to & operator
// Returns true if a valid int value was read
// Returns false otherwise
bool read_integer(FILE *stream, int *destination)
{
    // Don't skimp on memory
    char input[256];

    if (!fgets(input, sizeof input, stream))
    {
        // Failed to read from the input stream
        return false;
    }

    // Now try to parse the input (in base 10)
    char *end;
    long result = strtol(input, &end, 10);

    if (*end == '\0')
    {
        // We filled up the whole buffer with text!
        // That is either a value too big for us to handle
        // Or it contains invalid input (letters, etc.)
        // Either way, we need to flush the stream input and return as a failure
        // (We don't care about what the flush_input function returns)
        (void) flush_input(stream);

        return false;
    }

    if (*end != '\n')
    {
        // The input contains non-digit characters
        // This is a failure because we only allow digit-only input
        (void) flush_input(stream);

        return false;
    }

    if ((result == LONG_MAX || result == LONG_MIN) && errno == ERANGE)
    {
        // The input was a number, but either too large or too small for us to handle
        return false;
    }

    if (sizeof(int) < sizeof(long))
    {
        // The strtol function parses strings into a long integer
        // On this system the types int and long are not the same
        // So we need to add another over-/under-flow check for int
        if (result > INT_MAX || result < INT_MIN)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // If we come to this point, we have valid input and a valid number
    // Set the value and return with success
    *destination = result;
    return true;
}

// This function prompts the user for an integer input, and attempts to read it
// If the input fails for some reason, we retry for a few times
// Pass a pointer to the variable you want to read into using the pointer-to & operator
// Returns true if a valid int value was read
// Returns false otherwise
bool prompt_for_integer(const char *prompt, unsigned retries, int *destination)
{
    for (unsigned try = 0; try < retries; ++try)
    {
        printf("%s", prompt);
        if (read_integer(stdin, destination))
        {
            // Success!
            return true;
        }

        if (feof(stdin))
        {
            // The user gave the end-of-file input sequence
            return false;
        }

        if (ferror(stdin))
        {
            // There's an error in the input, just fail
            return false;
        }

        printf("Failed to read the input, or it was invalid.\n");
    }

    // If the loop ends, we're out of retries and fail
    return false;
}

int main(void)
{
    // The variable we try to fill
    int value;

    // Try to read an integer, but retry at most five times
    if (!prompt_for_integer("Please input an integer: ", 5, &value))
    {
        printf("I'm sorry, but you failed to input a valid integer.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Success! Your input is %d\n", value);
}
```

I use many different functions to keep functionality [separated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and easy to reuse and maintain.

The comments should hopefully be enough to explain what happens and why.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced: Real good input is tricky.

Say you create a user input function.  How to handle various below cases?

Once we know that, then write the code.

---

Normal: `"123\n"` --> nice and clean.  Read and return from input function.

Non-numeric: `"xyz\n"` or `"\n"` --> Read input line and try again.

Numeric, yet with junk: `"123xyz\n"` --> Read input line and try again.

Out of range of `int`: `"12345678901234567890\n"`  --> Read all input line and try again.

End-of-file: Give up reading and return indicate end-of-file.

Input error (rare): Example keyboard disappeared half-way though input. Give up reading and return indicate error.

---

Consider using `fgets()` to read a *line* of user input into a *string*, then process the string.

Avoid `scanf()` as it does not handle faulty *lines* of input well.